# Android webview setWebViewClient() show nothing

Tags: android, webview

guys! I have problem to load html page with ***android-webview***. I need to load the url with my webview but not with the mobile system broswer or other broswer, so I have to apply the method ***setWebViewClient()*** to my webview but not ***WebChromeClient()***. However, there's load nothing but blank page when applied the ***setWebViewClient()***, and works fine with the later method. I don't know where's problem, here is the code:

***.xml*** :

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
         android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

***.java*** :

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
}

private String loadUrl = "http://www.baidu.com";
webView.loadUrl(loadUrl);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
});

/*
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        Log.v(Log_Tag, String.valueOf(newProgress));
    }
});
*/
```

Comment: Shouldn't webView.loadUrl(loadUrl); be after you set the webviewclient?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Comment: Also, if you want your `WebView` to load the page, you should `return false;` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, and remove `view.loadUrl(url);`.

Comment: Well, @Mike M.! You're right, it's should ***return false*** to method ***shouldOverrideUrlLoading()***. Thanks so much, and thanks ***Smashing*** and ***IntelliJ Amiya*** too. And, I wonder how can I define a method to show the progress-change when loading the page like the method ***onProgressChanged*** in ***setWebChromeClient()*** ?

Comment: Well, that's how you do it. Set a `WebChromeClient` on the `WebView`, as well, and update your `ProgressBar`, or whatever, in `onProgressChanged()`.

Comment: Well, guys! I'm misunderstood of the two ***client-method***, I'm wonder the ***webView*** just can be applied one of them, but I'm wrong! The method ***setWebChromClient*** is a supporting way to make the ***webView*** available to some javascript-interactions ! Thanks @Mike M. again! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mike M. again. The method ***shouldOverrideUrlLoading()*** should ***return false*** if you want to loading the url with your webView but not with the mobile system default browser or other Third-Party browsers. And, if you want to deal some javascript actions of the webpage with your webView, you're suggested to apply the ***WebChromClient*** to your webView.

Here is the good example:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//load the page with cache
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
}


webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        //return true load with system-default-browser or other browsers, false with your webView
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
});

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        Log.v(Log_Tag, String.valueOf(newProgress));
        //put your code here if your want to show the progress with progressbar
    }
});

private String loadUrl = "http://www.baidu.com";
webView.loadUrl(loadUrl);
```

Comment: I would mention that the default behavior of the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method in the `WebViewClient` class is to just `return false;`, so if you don't actually need to override any of the other methods, you can just set a `WebViewClient` on the `WebView` without anonymously subclassing it. That is, `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in your activity

```
private String loadUrl = "https://www.google.com";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebViewClient mWebViewClient = new WebViewClient();
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
    mWebView.loadUrl(loadUrl);
}
```

You shouldn't override methods in WebViewClient class if you don't want to change their behavior or add some functionality.  And don't forget to add permission Internet to your manifest file. WebView will not work without it.

Comment: Hi, @HooliGun ! I'm really need to override some methods in ***WebViewClient*** to deal with the loading-state and other actions. The problem had been solved with the help of ***Mike M.*** I'll post an answer in detail later, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/");
```

> emphasized text

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).