# Problem with React.js Rendering in Android webview

Tags: android, reactjs, webview

My react.js app (created using create-react-app) is a one page application. It uses React, React-router.

I followed instructions from a youtube post on rendering the react app in android webview.

Here is the code in MainActivity.java in android app.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    **myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());**
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://quizmebuddy.com");
```

problem is, when setWebViewClient code is commented out, it is loading the URL correctly opening this in a browser.
To make it open within the browser, i need to use the line setWebViewClient. But when this is used, I am getting blank page getting rendered.

Can anyone help pls.

Comment: Which version of android are you targeting? Is it Pie?

Comment: Hi @dhruvsoni, it is 7.1.1

Comment: I faced this issue before for Pie. Why are you not using the React-native Webview? It would be much easier to integrate it with your react-native app. take a look at this if you still want to use the android webview - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494653/android-webview-setwebviewclient-show-nothing

Comment: @dhruvsoni, thank you. I will try out the option mentioned in your link. i.e returning false in 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading'. Also i first thought of trying the react-native way but the react-native webview is going to be removed as per this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview. Again thanks for taking time and helping me out. I will try this tonight.

Comment: cool. I think you misunderstood the explanation of removing webview in this doc - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview. They will separate it from the react-native core and make a separate module and separate github repo as react-native-webview. So they are just separating it from the core module and they will support it as they are doing right now.